# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') while using datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') while using the datatable.

typescript

```
 @ViewChild('dataTable',{static:false}) table;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      // if (!this.table) return;    
    this.dataTable=$(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable();
    console.log( this.dataTable.DataTable());
    
  }
```

HTML

```
<table #dataTable id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%"> 

  </table>
```

Comment: It should be `@ViewChild('dataTable'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @ViewChild('dataTable',{static:false}) table : ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      // if (!this.table) return;    
    this.dataTable=$(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable();
    console.log( this.dataTable.DataTable());
    
  }
```

Or you can use @ViewChild('dataTable',{static:false}) table : any;